# How tosave terminal output to a folder?

Tags: command-line

am tiring to do a multi operation with a soft ware , then   to How do I save each terminal output to a folder?

Comment: Please provide an example of those commands you want logged.

Comment: IIt matters what software u are using, GUI/CLI, and what are you trying to do exactly, create a log file? If so, you need to add more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If your command is this:

```
sudo apt-get install something
```

then run this:

```
sudo apt-get install something 2> file.txt
```